# Insert AngularJS directives (ng-click) in plain html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to insert specific AngularJS code within a plane HTML, and to compile it looks like this:

```
<a ng-click="viewUserstory(567456436)>
```

To do this, I have done the following:

In my service:

```
function parseScrumEvents(scrumMessageJSON) {

      var messageText = "<p><strong> #" + scrumMessageJSON.num + " </strong>" +
            "<a ng-click='viewUserstory("+scrumMessageJSON.userstory.id+")'>scrumMessageJSON.subject</a> </p>";

      return messageText;

 };
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.viewUserstory = function (userstoryid){
        console.log(userstoryid);
      };

$scope.getScrumMessage = function ($index) {
    var scrumMessageString = $scope.listaMensajes[$index].text;
    var scrumMessageMiddle = JSON.parse(scrumMessageString);
    var messageText = ScrumParseService.parseScrumEvents(scrumMessageMiddle);

    return messageText;

  };
```

In my HTML:

```
<span bind-html-compile="getScrumMessage($index)"></span>
```

In my directive:

```
angular.module('myAppAngularMinApp')
  .directive('bindHtmlCompile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(function () {
          return scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtmlCompile);
        }, function (value) {
          // In case value is a TrustedValueHolderType, sometimes it
          // needs to be explicitly called into a string in order to
          // get the HTML string.
          element.html(value && value.toString());
          // If scope is provided use it, otherwise use parent scope
          var compileScope = scope;
          if (attrs.bindHtmlScope) {
            compileScope = scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtmlScope);
          }
          $compile(element.contents())(compileScope);
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

But, my browser console returns me error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'b73ecf1f7b15315359e96' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 18 of the expression [viewUserstory(574b73ecf1f7b15315359e96)] starting at [b73ecf1f7b15315359e96)].
```

I have no idea how to program it to work.
If you know other ways to do it, also would be helpful.
Any ideas?
Thank you very much for your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use quotes (simples or doubles) and surround your dynamic value.

Your service should lool like this:

```
function parseScrumEvents(scrumMessageJSON) {

  var messageText = "<p><strong> #" + scrumMessageJSON.num + " </strong>" +
        "<a ng-click='viewUserstory(" + '"'+scrumMessageJSON.userstory.id+'"'+")'>scrumMessageJSON.subject</a> </p>";

  return messageText;
};
```

> It could happen because angular thinks that your dyinamic value passed
>   in your function in the ng-clik binding is a identifier ( name of a
>   variable in your scope).

I guess you're trying to pass a value to your function, based on that, you need to use quotes.

Comment: It works perfectly, but when I hit the link is evaluated again ng-if I have on the page.
You know it can be?